# How to loop/iterate over a 2D array using every()?

Tags: javascript, loops, methods

I cannot find a solution that uses method every(). I want to see if each coordinate (both x and y) is <= 10. So, the following example should return true.

Here is my code:

```
const shipLocation = [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 3 ] ]
const outOfBounds = function (shipLocation) {
    Array.every(locationPoint => 
      // code here!
      locationPoint <= 10;
    );
  };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const shipLocation = [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 3 ] ]
const outOfBounds = shipLocation.every(cords=> (cords[0]<=10) && (cords[1]<=10))
```

Comment: Why is it returning false? It should return true!

Comment: You are right, now it takes the coordinates correctly

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to return a value (boolean: true or false) from your function.
2. You have nested arrays so you need to use `every` on each of them *and* check that values inside those arrays are less or equal to 10 also by using `every` again, making sure you return true or false from that callback too.

```js
const shipLocation=[[2,1],[3,3],[4,3],[5,3],[6,3]]
const shipLocation2=[[2,41],[3,3],[4,3],[5,3],[6,3]];

function outOfBounds(shipLocation) {

  // For every ship location array
  return shipLocation.every(arr => {

    // Return whether every value is <= 10
    return arr.every(el => el <= 10);
  });
};

console.log(outOfBounds(shipLocation));
console.log(outOfBounds(shipLocation2));
```

Comment: Is this considered a nested loop?

Comment: I guess so, but I tend to think of nested loops with [`for in` or `for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loops rather more functional iterative code.

Comment: Any idea what Big O is going to be?

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: The biggest is 2D array of 5 elements each is 2 elements.

Comment: Then it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the `flat()` function to make the 2d array into a 1d array:

```js
const shipLocation = [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 6, 3 ] ];
const outOfBounds =
    shipLocation.flat().every(locationPoint =>  
        locationPoint <= 10   // do not put ";"
    );
  
console.log(outOfBounds);
```